# mysqli_connect is not working

Tags: php, mysql, cpanel

When I call `var_dump(function_exists('mysqli_connect'))`, it returned `bool(false)` and my `mysqli_connect` function didn't work, [eventhough I checked mysqli in the cpanel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NAG6T.png). Does that mean the mysqli is still not installed on the host? My host is from a2hosting.

Comment: You'll probably get better help if you ask your hosting service support team about this issue.

Comment: can you post your actual code or at least part of it?

Answer (score 4):

What does it say about MySQLiwhen you print out the PHP info?

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Try turning it off and on again. Also try it on a different PHP version. Otherwise this is about as much as you can try within the bounds of cPanel, contact your host. :)

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton - It provides the definitive answer for a particular installation as to whether mysqli is installed and additional information about it - e.g., on my server it shows: Client API library version, Active Persistent Links, Inactive Persistent Links, Active Links